# Two Queueable jobs keep triggering the same trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, recursion, queueable

So we have managed package that have a trigger on update Contact, lets call it Trigger1. Trigger one call a manged Queueable class that updates Contact.

We have Trigger on update for contacts, lets call it Trigger2. Trigger2 also calls a Queueable class that updates the contact.
So when we update the contact both triggers run and and adds the methods to the queue, and each time one run it causes an update that kicks the other method to be queued. That keeps happening forever.

I tried a utility class on our class as I cant modify or see the managed class. It didnt work, I think because its a brand new update the context is lost and it thinks its a completely new trigger and not a recursive trigger.
here is my code:
The Queueable class:

```
public class FPU_Calc_Driving_Time implements Queueable,  
Database.AllowsCallouts{
List<Contact> contactList;
public FPU_Calc_Driving_Time(List<Contact> contList) {
    contactList=contList;
}
public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
FPU_Bing_API.Update_Driving_TimeDistance(contactList);
TriggerHelpper.firstRun=false;
}   
}
```

The Trigger helper:

```
public class TriggerHelpper {
public static boolean firstRun = true;
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger FPU_ContactTrigger on Contact (after insert,after update) {
system.debug('Email from contact trigger--> '+Trigger.New[0].email);
system.debug('Contact trigger--> '+Trigger.New[0]);
    //this is where we try to determine id it ran already 
   if(TriggerHelpper.firstRun=true && !system.isScheduled()){
    List<contact> contactAddressList =new List<contact>();
    List<contact> contactList =new List<contact>();
    for( Id con : Trigger.newMap.keySet() )
    {

    //Uses FPU_Bing_APITest as a test class
    system.debug('****Before Driving calc');
    if( (Trigger.isUpdate  && Trigger.oldMap.get( con ).Driving_Distance_to_Campus__c==null)||(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.oldMap.get( con ).smartystreets__Mailing_Verified__c != Trigger.newMap.get( con ).smartystreets__Mailing_Verified__c) || (Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.newMap.get( con ).MailingStreet<>null))
    {
        system.debug('****Enter Driving calc');
        contactAddressList.add(Trigger.newMap.get( con ));
    }
    }

    if(contactAddressList.size()>0)
    {
        system.debug('****Add driving job');
      //This is where it calls the job
     System.enqueueJob(new FPU_Calc_Driving_Time(contactAddressList));
    }
    TriggerHelpper.firstRun=false;
   }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Before Triggers

If you put your updates in a before trigger, there will be no need for a DML statement to perform operations and as such no additional triggers are fired.

### Verifying the change is valid before applying it

My primary tool for preventing trigger recursion is to make sure that you are only updating records that actually need to be updated.

For instance, we use Salesforce's CPQ package which uses a custom Object for quoting. As a result we have a custom trigger that syncs fields from opp to the custom quote and vice versa.

Here is a snippet:

```
for (SBQQ__Quote__c primaryQuote : primaryQuotes) {
    Opportunity compareOpp = primaryQuoteOpps.get(primaryQuote.SBQQ__Opportunity2__c);

    if (compareOpp != null) {
        for (String quoteField : quoteToOppSettings.keySet()) {
            QuoteToOppSyncFields__c setting = quoteToOppSettings.get(quoteField);
            String oppField = setting.OppFieldAPIName__c;

            if (
                primaryQuote.get(quoteField) != compareOpp.get(oppField) && setting.Active__c && 
                (primaryQuote.get(quoteField) != null || setting.SyncNulls__c)
            ) {
                if (!oppsToUpdate.containsKey(compareOpp.Id)) {
                    oppsToUpdate.put(compareOpp.Id, new Opportunity(Id = compareOpp.Id));
                }

                oppsToUpdate.get(compareOpp.Id).put(oppField, primaryQuote.get(quoteField));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pay attention to the fact that we are only adding opp's to our map where the opp value is different than the quote value. If the values are the same a sync would cause an infinite loop.

This will result in just enough recursion to verify that the change has completed successfully.

In your case, since your managed package is firing the queueable you don't have control of that half of the equation. What you do have control over is your own triggers. So, in your triggers, do not trigger a change that would re-fire the queueable unless absolutely necessary.

### Last Resort

We have a trigger management class that we use that controls various features and triggers. It uses a combination of custom settings (global settings) and Static variables (Just in Time, context specific settings) to control whether or not our triggers fire or certain methods within a trigger fire (feature management). This is similar to your "first run" approach above but is much cleaner and much more powerful.

If we absolutely can't use either of the above methods, we will usually disable a trigger just in time. I am not confident this approach will work for you as the queueable is async which fires in a second context and is in a managed package so you can't customize it to prevent it from firing your triggers.

Comment: Thanks, thats the route I am taking now, but in case I cant think of a scenario and the  update still happens it could result in infinite ping pong which is what scares me.